# Can I connect headers and footers across nonconsecutive sections?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document that has headers and footers that span the entire page. There's a section in the middle that is in landscape while the rest of the document is in portrait, and I have unchecked the "link to previous" button in the header/footer menu to allow me to change the dimensions of the header content. Is there a way to connect the portrait sections while excluding the landscape sections?

Put more simply, can I connect the headers of section 5 and section 7 to section 3 without also including section 4 and section 6?